# Do for-profit prisons lobby against early childhood education?

Tags: united-states

This [popular reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/kmf1qb/what_is_the_worst_thing_that_is_legal/ghevcdu/) claims that for profit prisons "...literally lobby against things like early child education..."

I can't find any evidence for or against this claim.  I've found many articles against for profit prisons, noting their conflict of interest with public good, but no specific evidence.  Do for-profit prisons actually pay lobbyists to fight early child education?

Comment: Huh.  Normally, I wouldn't think of "reddit comment" as notable, but 12.4k upvotes has a notability all its own

Comment: In further support of this claim's notability, the original comment has (at the time I am writing this) a whopping 35.8 thousand responses, most of which seem to accept the claim without question. If the main criterion for notability here is "The claim is believed by a large number of people", this claim definitely qualifies.

Comment: Given the definition of the word *like*, I highly doubt it's not true. Surely some of them lobby for *something*. ... "Do for-profit prisons lobby against [things *like*] early childhood education?"

Comment: Meh, it might be something like: they opposed more funding for pre-schools [or something like that], which many business might do because something like that may require taxes to be raised. Look at https://www.pewtrusts.org/~/media/legacy/uploadedfiles/pcs_assets/2008/pewpknfundingthefuturefeb2008pdf some "red states" don't fund pre-schools at all.

Comment: That same user posted [other relevant comments](https://web.archive.org/web/20201231025535/https://www.reddit.com/user/stos313/comments/). Unfortunately, when asked for a source for the claim in question, the response was: "Honestly, it was just conversations I had with leg staffers who would always complain when they had meetings like that. I wish I had some documentation - but you get used to crap like that."